# SUPEE-8167 - PayPal IPN patch, Safe to Install right now?

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

Magento released SUPEE 8167, IPN patch, basically after JUNE 30, 2017, PayPal will start using HTTPS URL (secured) for IPN communication. Currently they are accepting HTTP requests.

Is it safe to install the patch RIGHT NOW, or it better to wait closer to Deadline ?

Comment: Ensure that the store has a valid ssl certificate setup and is working properly then install the patch. No reason to wait.

Comment: Great, light patch, easy install.

Answer (score 5):

It seems safe to update already as the change mentioned on the PayPal page mentions to accept **HTTPS only** after this date. Currently they are accepting HTTP and HTTPS requests. Thus you can already send your requests via HTTPS already.

See also: 
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1916

Comment: Great, I've updated, everything works fine. At least I haven't found issues :)

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I wanted to check this patch to make sure the code affected wasn't extended anywhere in my shops, strange thing is the patch is has an EE prefix and I cannot find the changes it makes in the latest 1.9.3.3 code at app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php at all, am I missing something here?

Comment: @paj look closely the changes should be made in 19.3.3. They mentioned it in the release notes. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1933

Comment: do you guys knows what happened to this patch, it is not available anymore ...

Comment: The patch is still available on this page: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download > switch to the release archive tab!

Answer (score 2):

See here to clear up confusion of this patch's differences to magento 1.9.3.3: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8167-not-included-in-1-9-3-3/m-p/68857

Answer (score 1):

I run the patch as a php script because I have no ssh-access:

```
<?php
 print("<PRE>");
 passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-8167_EE_1.14.0.0_1.14.0.1_v1-2017-05-08-02-41-29.sh");
 print("</PRE>");
 echo "Done";
?>
```

and it said "Done" (nothing else, maybe it was too fast). 
How can I check if everything worked? If I check the last edited time stamp on the ftp server in /htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php it still gives me a old date (january 2017)

Comment: The only way you can check is by going to app/etc/applied.patches and view the list. See if SUPEE-8167 in installed.

Comment: However, if you see ipn.php dated as of Jan 2017. most likely it didn't install

Comment: You can also look at file `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php`.  If `DEFAULT_POSTBACK_URL` and `SANDBOX_POSTBACK_URL` are declared and using https urls, the patch was applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it now, Because all higher version of magento [ Magento 1.9.3.3 >] already have the patch installed so its good to install it before the deadline.
You can find more instruction of instillation here.
http://www.tricoreitsolutions.com/how-to-install-supee-8167

You can find commands for installation through SSH.

Comment: Note : Here you need to set POST back URL of  PayPal to https:// instead of http://. It does not mean that you need to install SSL on your store for your IPN to run on.