# Security Patch SUPEE-8167 - possible problems?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, patches, supee-8167

I noticed a security message on my magento admin panel. I have proceeded to apply the patch but Is there anyone who can tell what are the possible areas need to test after applying this patch?

It's obvious that I need to check if paypal payment method is working or not. Apart from that, any tweaks I need to do?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175167/supee-8167-paypal-ipn-patch-safe-to-install-right-now

Comment: After installing this patch on magento version 1.9.0.1 facing redirect problem in paypal express checkout. Order went through the system successfully but on frontside after placing order it is redirect to cart page and giving error "unable to initialize express checkout" any solutions?

Comment: I'm using iwd onepage checkout and i guess need to change iwd onepage checkout code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have magento 1.9.3.3 installed, then the new PayPal changes are applied.

However, NOTE the patch changes are implemented DIFFERENTLY than how magento 1.9.3.3 does this.

I.e. the end result in posting to PayPal is the same, however, the code is structured significantly different between what the patch does and how Magento 1.9.3.3 is coded.

See: https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8167-not-included-in-1-9-3-3/m-p/68857

Best bet, especially for future updates and patches is to simply update to Magento 1.9.3.3 rather than messing with SUPEE-8167 patch.

Comment: agree to you @duntuk, but the question here is about the possible problems (if any) if someone goes with the patch in their old versions!